# Creating an Arc between Two Points with Arc Radius and Rotation

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Points I want to connect with an Arc in the C# Graphics Class when my main form is painted. I also have the radius that arc should have and the direction the arc should turn from starting point to the next. I dont see how I should do that with the drawArc overloads provided. Can anybody help me with maybe a function that takes a starting point, a end point, an arc radius and a direction (Clockwise or counter-Clockwise) and then draws that arc? Or Rather I am trying to parse this from how .gcode files specify arc movements and if the radius is negative its a clockwise roation and vice versa.
Am looking forward to some input

Comment: This is rather for https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: You will need to find the center C of the circle and the angle from C to a point. There will be 2 circles and 4 arcs.

Comment: You don't stand much of a chance when you get started wrong.  There are *four* ways to draw an arc like that.  The G-code tells you whether it goes CW or CCW, a negative radius tells you to take the one that rotates more than 180 degrees.  Do the math for the simple case, the two points having the same Y value.  Get there by rotating p2 around p1 by the angle. The center.x is then (p2.x - p1.x) / 2, center.y is -sqrt(r * r - (center.x - p1.x) * (center.x - p1.x)).  If it is CCW then flip the center.y sign, if r is negative then flip center.y sign.  Rotate the center back for the general case.

Comment: Can you provide some example values  (point locations and radius) so we can test our code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out for you.

[image: fig]

Here is the sample code. The key here is the function `DrawArcBetweenTwoPoints()`. For testing it also draws the center points and the two spokes. You should remove those lines and focus on the `DrawArc()` part.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(ClientSize.Width/2, ClientSize.Height/2);

        PointF A = new PointF(0, -40);

        PointF B = new PointF(100, 40);

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.DarkBlue, A, B);
        DrawPoint(e.Graphics, Brushes.Black, A);
        DrawPoint(e.Graphics, Brushes.Black, B);

        DrawArcBetweenTwoPoints(e.Graphics, Pens.Red, A, B, 100);
        
    }

    public void DrawPoint(Graphics g, Brush brush, PointF A, float size = 8f)
    {
        g.FillEllipse(brush, A.X-size/2, A.Y-size/2, size, size);
    }

    public void DrawArcBetweenTwoPoints(Graphics g, Pen pen,  PointF a, PointF b, float radius, bool flip = false)
    {
        if (flip)
        {
            PointF temp = b;
            b =a;
            a = temp;
        }

        // get distance components
        double x = b.X-a.X, y = b.Y-a.Y;
        // get orientation angle
        var θ = Math.Atan2(y, x);
        // length between A and B
        var l = Math.Sqrt(x*x+y*y);
        if (2*radius>=l)
        {
            // find the sweep angle (actually half the sweep angle)
            var φ = Math.Asin(l/(2*radius));
            // triangle height from the chord to the center
            var h = radius*Math.Cos(φ);
            // get center point. 
            // Use sin(θ)=y/l and cos(θ)=x/l
            PointF C = new PointF(
                (float)(a.X + x/2 - h*(y/l)),
                (float)(a.Y + y/2 + h*(x/l)));

            g.DrawLine(Pens.DarkGray, C, a);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.DarkGray, C, b);
            DrawPoint(g, Brushes.Orange, C);

            // Conversion factor between radians and degrees
            const double to_deg = 180/Math.PI;

            // Draw arc based on square around center and start/sweep angles
            g.DrawArc(pen, C.X-radius, C.Y-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius,
                (float)((θ-φ)*to_deg)-90, (float)(2*φ*to_deg));
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

I tested the flip arc with the following code

```
DrawArcBetweenTwoPoints(e.Graphics, Pens.Red, A, B, 100);
DrawArcBetweenTwoPoints(e.Graphics, Pens.Red, A, B, 100, true);
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: sir, whatis to_deg?

Comment: @ZenOfKursat `to_deg = 180/π` it converts radians (the result of `atan()`) to degrees, needed in the draw routines.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

I recommend using a **Bezier Curve**.
An implementation is shown below which you can adapt for your arc.
The BezierCurve (check Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawbezier?view=netframework-4.8)) is a curve described fully by 4 points.

The start/end points should be clear. 
The **control** points define the **curvature** of the arc.

You will need to calculate the control points yourself. I recommend trying *Code Sample 1* to see how it functions and then adapting the second code sample for your specific purposes. Change the values of the ComputedRotationAngleA/B, flip them around. Change the ControlPointDistance amount. You should be able to get a good idea of how the C# implentation of it works.

Then calculate your own values and plug them into the Code provided in *Code Sample 2*.

Note:

*ComputedRotationAngleA/B* control the direction of the arc.

*ControlPointDistance* controls the point where the curvature is added to the arc.

Good luck!

**Code Sample 1:**

```
        internal void DrawBezierCurveTest(Pen pen, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int ComputedRotationAngleA = 20, ComputedRotationAngleB = -20;
            int ControlPointDistance = 5;
            LinePath = new GraphicsPath();
            var p1 = new Point(StartX, StartY);
            var p2 = new Point(StartX + ControlPointDistance , StartY + ControlPointDistance );
            p2.Offset(ComputedRotationAngleA, ComputedRotationAngleA);
            var p3 = new Point(EndX - ControlPointDistance , EndY - ControlPointDistance );
            p3.Offset(ComputedRotationAngleB, ComputedRotationAngleB);
            var p4 = new Point(EndX , EndY);
            LinePath.AddBezier(p1, p2, p3, p4);
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, LinePath);
        }
```

**Code Sample 2:**

```
        internal void DrawBezierCurve(Pen pen, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            LinePath = new GraphicsPath();
            var p1 = new Point(StartX, StartY); //starting point
            var p2 = new Point(FirstDipX, FirstDipY) //first control point
            var p3 = new Point(SecondDipX, SecondDipY); //second control point
            var p4 = new Point(EndX, EndY); //ending point
            LinePath.AddBezier(p1, p2, p3, p4);
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, LinePath);
        }
```

Comment: Given that all arcs and ellipses in a GraphicsPath get converted to beziers anyway, this is excellent advice and imo easier to implement that the accepted answer..