# Draw an ellipse arc between two points in Three.js

Tags: math, three.js, ellipse

I've been trying to draw an ellipse arc between two arbitrary points but my implementation is not working in some situations.

Because a part of this is involves mathematics, I started by asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567842/is-it-always-possible-to-draw-an-ellipse-given-any-two-points-and-the-center).
Basically, given two points and the center, you can always get an ellipse if you allow rotation, except for cases where the points are collinear.

The solution proposed to that question is to:

1. Translate the center to the origin, translating both points by the same vector.
2. Rotate both points by the angle `-alpha` which is the simetric of the angle of the largest vector with the positive x-semiaxis.
3. Solve the ellipse equation to find its radiuses (system of two equations with two unknowns).
4. Define the ellipse
5. Rotate back the ellipse with the angle `alpha` and translate back to its center.

However, I'm having trouble implementing this in Three.js. 
The documentation for the [EllipseCurve](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/curves/EllipseCurve) lists the expected parameters. I assume the starting angle to always be zero and then set the end angle to either the angle between the two vectors or its simetric. I also want the arc to always be the smallest (i.e., if the angle is bigger than 180º, I'd use the complementary arc). I assume the center of the ellipse to be the middle point between the centers of the shape's bounding boxes.

This is my example code:
https://jsfiddle.net/at5dc7yk/1/
This example tries to create an arc from a vertex in the original shape and the same vertex in the modified shape.
Code regarding the ellipse arc is under the class `EllipseArc` and you can mess with the transformation applied to the object in line 190.

It works for some cases:
[image: Example working]

But not all:
[image: Example not working]

Comment: And what happens in bad case?  Wrong ellipse is calculated? Correct ellipse but wrong arcs?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `EllipseCurve`.

Comment: @prisoner849 I don't know how to do without it.

Comment: Related? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58824801/380384

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an idea from scratch, not the ultimate solution.

When you clone and translate object, to build an arc between two respective points you'll need their coordinates in world coordinate system, and a coordinate of the middle point between centroids of objects.

1. Find the mid point between points in world space (between start and end vectors).
2. Find its projection on the vector of translation (this is the center of an arc).
3. Find the angle between vectors that you get by subtraction the result center vector from each of them.
4. Divide an angle by amount of divisions - you'll get the step value.
5. Get the end vector as the base and rotate it around an axis (which is the normal of a triangle, built with start, center, end vectors) in a loop, multiplying that step angle value with the number of the current iteration.

Code example:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 150);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var shapeGeom = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry(new THREE.Shape(californiaPts));
shapeGeom.center();
shapeGeom.scale(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);

var shapeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "orange"
});
var shape = new THREE.Mesh(shapeGeom, shapeMat);
shape.updateMatrixWorld();
scene.add(shape);

var shapeClone = shape.clone();
shapeClone.position.set(25, 25, 0);
shapeClone.updateMatrixWorld();
scene.add(shapeClone);

var center = new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(shapeClone.position, shape.position, 0.5);
var vecStart = new THREE.Vector3();
var vecEnd = new THREE.Vector3();
var pos = shapeGeom.getAttribute("position");

for (let i = 0; i < pos.count; i++) {
  vecStart.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i);
  shape.localToWorld(vecStart);
  vecEnd.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i);
  shapeClone.localToWorld(vecEnd);
  makeArc(center, vecStart, vecEnd);
}

function makeArc(center, start, end) {

  console.log(center, start, end);


  let vM = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(start, end).multiplyScalar(0.5);
  let dir = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(end, start).normalize();

  let c = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(vM, center);
  let d = c.dot(dir);
  c.copy(dir).multiplyScalar(d).add(center); // get a center of an arc

  let vS = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(start, c);
  let vE = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(end, c);
  let a = vS.angleTo(vE); // andgle between start and end, relatively to the new center



  let divisions = 100;
  let aStep = a / divisions;
  let pts = [];
  let vecTemp = new THREE.Vector3();
  let tri = new THREE.Triangle(start, c, end);
  let axis = new THREE.Vector3();
  tri.getNormal(axis); // get the axis to rotate around
  for (let i = 0; i <= divisions; i++) {

    vecTemp.copy(vE);
    vecTemp.applyAxisAngle(axis, aStep * i);
    pts.push(vecTemp.clone());

  }

  let g = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(pts);
  let m = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    dashSize: 1,
    gapSize: 1
  });
  let l = new THREE.Line(g, m);
  l.computeLineDistances();
  l.position.copy(c);

  scene.add(l);

}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script>
  var californiaPts = [
    new THREE.Vector2(610, 320),
    new THREE.Vector2(450, 300),
    new THREE.Vector2(392, 392),
    new THREE.Vector2(266, 438),
    new THREE.Vector2(190, 570),
    new THREE.Vector2(190, 600),
    new THREE.Vector2(160, 620),
    new THREE.Vector2(160, 650),
    new THREE.Vector2(180, 640),
    new THREE.Vector2(165, 680),
    new THREE.Vector2(150, 670),
    new THREE.Vector2(90, 737),
    new THREE.Vector2(80, 795),
    new THREE.Vector2(50, 835),
    new THREE.Vector2(64, 870),
    new THREE.Vector2(60, 945),
    new THREE.Vector2(300, 945),
    new THREE.Vector2(300, 743),
    new THREE.Vector2(600, 473),
    new THREE.Vector2(626, 425),
    new THREE.Vector2(600, 370),
    new THREE.Vector2(610, 320)
  ];
</script>
```

If you don't translate, and just rotate an object, in this case you don't need to compute a new center for each arc, just omit that step, as all the centers are equal to the centroid of the object.

I hope I explained it in more or less understandable way ^^

Comment: Thank you so much for all your work! I haven't tested it, but it seems to work perfectly in your example.

Comment: I've been trying to fit your code into my example but I've not had any success. I'm already basically working in world space so I didn't think I needed your pre-processing before calling `makeArc` but somehow it's not working. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q1owxpna/2/. There you'll find a mix between your code and mine. Using `shapeGeometry.center` and getting the center from its position is not going to work for me since it breaks other stuff :( I've been getting my center from the bounding boxes in world space (line 200). Can you please take a look? Your solution seems incredible!

Comment: Essentially, the rotations or translation that I apply are just an example of the vertices that may come to me to display. I cannot relly on object space. I treat all vertices as world space and display them directly. From what I saw, the points created for the line arc are all (0,0,0) in the fiddle :(

Comment: I centered the main geometry just for eductional purpose. If you want to know the center of a geometry, use `THREE.Box3().setFromObject()` and its `.getCenter()` method. We can continue in this forum thread :) https://discourse.threejs.org/t/draw-an-ellipse-arc-between-two-points/13784?u=prisoner849

Comment: Thank you for everything! I wish I could mark this as correct twice! I got it working just this second! My vertices were 2D and the lack of a Z coordinate was causing NaNs.